# Is tight coupling between the model and the UI avoidable when using RichFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, ejb-3.0, seam, richfaces

I am using RichFaces with seam and EJB3.  Specifically I am using the rich:tree component.  The problem I am worried about is the tight coupling between the UI and my EJB3 session bean.  In order to make the tree view work, I was forced to include the Richfaces jar files in my EJB3 project.  Is this a bad thing?

The method below is called when a node is selected in the RichFaces tree component.  Adding this method to my session bean was what caused me to need to include the RichFaces jars.

```
public void processSelection(NodeSelectedEvent event) {
    HtmlTree tree = (HtmlTree) event.getComponent();
    selectedNode = (String) tree.getRowData();
}
```

Am I doing this all wrong, or is this not really a problem to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

- getting the `HtmlTree` in a managed bean and parse its data, transforming it to a usable data-structure with no UI-elements.
- pass that data to the EJB.